# Simple pointer arithmetic not working?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char * str = "Hello";

*(str+1) = '3';

cout<<str;
```

What I was trying to do there was to change the second character into '3', turning it into H3llo

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour. You cannot change literal.

To have a pointer to literal, it should be:

```
  const char* str = "Hello";
//^^^^^
```

Then, to be able to change string, this should be, for example

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

The other option is to allocate dynamically the memory (using `malloc` and `free`)

Comment: So an error occurred because the compiler caught it or because the program somehow crashed when I tried to rewrite in that memory location?

Comment: @user1091856 - If the compiler have caught it, then there will be a compiler error. If the program crash, it will immediately exit. But it's not necessary to crash. You are not allowed to change that memory and if you try to change it, anything could happen. That's why it's _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 2):

string literals are allocated in read only memory.so basically they are of type(`const char *`).It cannot be changed.
Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because str is of type "const char *" and you are not allowed to overwrite the object it points to.

Comment: If you mean the literal, it's technically `const char[6]`, not `const char *`.

Comment: in terms of type safety...yes

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
char *str;
if((str = malloc(strlen("hello"))) != NULL)
  return (null);
str = strcpy(str, "hello");
printf("%s\n", str); // should print hello
str[2] = '3';
printf("%s\n", str) // should print he3lo
```

The thing here is that i allocate memory before to set char in the string.
But if you're not good with allocation you can always set the char str[] = "hello";

Comment: The thing is, why use heap allocation when you don't need to? One of the things it leads to is that missing `free` call.

Comment: True to this. Still, its a good way to see the different options

Answer (score 0):

Memory for `str` will be allocated in `.rodata` section. so trying to modify read only data will produce problem.

The following problem gives issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char * str = "Hello";

printf("\n%s \n", str);
*(str+1) = '3';
printf("\n%s \n", str);


return 0;
}
```

corresponding dis-assembly

```
 .file   "dfd.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello"
.LC1:
        .string "\n%s \n"
        .text
  .....
  .....
```

And the result is

```
Hello 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Im using gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) on X86_64.

Answer (score 0):

str is a pointer to string constant and memory for the string is allocated in read-only section . If u try to modify the string content the result is undefined. However you can modify the pointer to point something else as compared to an array-name which is always bound to same memory location.